# JsonSyntaxException : Expected a String but was NAME

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm having some problems with parsing JSON from a 3rd party.

```
"field_head_picture":{  
      "und":[  
         {  
            "fid":"11917",
            "uid":"1",
            "filename":"fr_bril_id_promo.jpg",
            "uri":"public://fr_bril_id_promo.jpg",
            "filemime":"image/jpeg",
            "filesize":"12744",
            "status":"1",
            "timestamp":"1429724219",
            "uuid":"bb8c1a73-451c-4e17-9001-146c6e06f255",
            "display":"1",
            "description":""
         }
      ]
}
```

and sometimes it returns

```
 "field_head_picture":[  

 ],
```

As you can see it returns an object or an empty array. I know this is bad JSON design but I can't change it..

So I've wrote a TypeAdapter

```
FieldHeadPictureTypeAdapter headPictureTypeAdapter = new FieldHeadPictureTypeAdapter();

return new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(FieldHeadPicture.class, headPictureTypeAdapter)
            .create();
```

This is my TypeAdapter

```
public class FieldHeadPictureTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<FieldHeadPicture> {

private Gson gson = new Gson();

@Override
public void write(JsonWriter out, FieldHeadPicture value) throws IOException {
    gson.toJson(value, FieldHeadPicture.class, out);
}

@Override
public FieldHeadPicture read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
    try {
        JsonToken peek = jsonReader.peek();

        if (peek == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            jsonReader.beginArray();
            jsonReader.endArray();
            return new FieldHeadPicture();
        } else if (peek == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            jsonReader.beginObject();
            FieldHeadPicture picture =  new Gson().fromJson(jsonReader.nextString(), FieldHeadPicture.class);
            jsonReader.endObject();
            return picture;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new FieldHeadPicture();
    }
    return new FieldHeadPicture();
}
```

I just want to return an empty FieldHeadPicture if the array is empty and parse to an FieldHeadPicture object otherwise.
But I get an error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was NAME at line 1 column 622 path $.field_head_picture.

This is my FieldHeadPicture class

```
public class FieldHeadPicture {

   @SerializedName("und")
   private List<Und> und;

   public List<Und> getListFieldAdditionalPicture() {
       return und;
   }

   public FieldHeadPicture() {
   }
}
```

Comment: if you just use the code after the else if (peek == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) and comment out all of the if statement, what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want to call `nextString()` on the `JsonReader`, but rather directly deserialize the enclosed object, using the Gson instance you've already created instead of a new one.  In other words, your else clause becomes simply:

```
    } else if (peek == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
        return gson.fromJson(jsonReader, FieldHeadPicture.class);
    }
```

No need for the `beginObject()` / `endObject()` this way either.  Let me know if that doesn't work and I can post a test case for you.